# Validar registro y compararlo con textbox, alguien que me pueda ayudar! Query1 es igual que TextBox1.Text pero no me lo valida me manda else

Tags: c#

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCafeteriaConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    con.Open();
    string Query1 = "select Id from Tbl_Empleados where Id='" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
    string query2 = "select Id from Tbl_Registros where Id='" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
    string insert = "insert into Tbl_Registros (Id,Num_Empleado,Nombre,Apellido,Fecha_Hora) values (@Id,@Num_Empleado,@Nombre,@Apellido,@Fecha_Hora)";

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text))
    {
        Lbl_Mensaje.Text = ("Error");
    }
    else
    {

        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(Query1, con);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();


        if (Query1 == TextBox1.Text)
        {
            Lbl_Mensaje.Text = ("paso query 1!!!");
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query2, con);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", TextBox1.Text);
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (query2 == TextBox1.Text)
            {
                Lbl_Mensaje.Text = ("Empleado ya registrado el dia de hoy!!!");

                con.Close();
            }
            else
            {

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert, con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", TextBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Num_Empleado", TextBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", TextBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Apellido", TextBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha_Hora", DateTime.Now);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                Lbl_Mensaje.Text = ("Empleado  registrado correctamente!!!");

            }

        }
        else
        {
            Lbl_Mensaje.Text = ("Empleado no existe!!!");

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. En este caso, lo único que muestras en un código, pero no nos dices que te falla en el. Te lanza alguna excepción? Los resultados no son los esperados? Pulsa en [edit] y añade toda la información que sea relevante.

Comment: Cámbiale el nombre lo primero, no es una "buena costumbre" llamar a las variables empezando por mayúsculas. Además, si query1 es igual a algo más el contenido de un textbox, nunca va a ser igual al texto del textbox, ya que has añadido algo más

Comment: Adaptando el comentario de Pablo. Si string Query1 = "select Id from Tbl_Empleados where Id='" + TextBox1.Text + "'"; entonces Query1 == TextBox1.Text no puede ser nunca true. Que tratabas de hacer?

Comment: tengo un textbox al ingresarle un numero lo debe buscar en una tabla para verificar que exista que me daria como resultado query1 pero al compararlo query1== TextBox1.Text no me da true, como le puedo hacer?

Comment: Debe guardar en algunn lugar el resultado del query y ese valor es el que se compara con el textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para poder validar necesitas el `SqlDataReader` te muestro un ejemplo de código:

```
    public bool VerificarEmpleado() // Este metodo te sirve para regresar una valor Boolenao (TRUE O FLASE)
    {
        bool respuesta = false;
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Id from Tbl_Empleados where Id='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read() == true)
        {
            respuesta = true; //la varibable se establece en TRUE
        }
        con.Close();
        return respuesta; // te regresa el valor 
    }
```

Comment: Gracias CarlosR93 es exactamente lo que estaba buscando!!